# Pass cardview in RecyclerView A to RecyclerView B

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bundle

I have 2 RecyclerView A and B that they are in Fragment. I put data ItemModel for cardview in RecyclerView A. Now I want to pass this cardview to RecyclerView B.

**ItemsModel**

```
public class ItemsModel {
    private int itemID;
    private Bitmap itemImage;
    private String itemColor;
    private String itemBrand;
    private String itemKind;
    private String itemCat;

    public ItemsModel(){

    }

    public void setItemID(int itemID){
        this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    public void setItemImage(Bitmap itemImage){
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }

    public void setItemColor(String itemColor){
        this.itemColor = itemColor;
    }

    public void setItemBrand(String itemBrand){
        this.itemBrand = itemBrand;
    }

    public  void setItemKind(String itemKind){
        this.itemKind = itemKind;
    }

    public void setItemCat(String itemCat) { this.itemCat = itemCat; }

    public int getItemID(){
        return this.itemID;
    }

    public Bitmap getItemImage(){
        return this.itemImage;
    }

    public String getItemColor(){
        return this.itemColor;
    }

    public String getItemBrand(){
        return this.itemBrand;
    }

    public String getItemKind(){
        return this.itemKind;
    }

    public String getItemCat(){ return this.itemCat;}

}
```

And there is **RecyclerViewAdapter A**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final ItemsModel itemsModel = listModel.get(position);

        holder.itemDetail.setText(String.valueOf(itemsModel.getItemBrand()));
        holder.itemImg.setImageBitmap(itemsModel.getItemImage());

        holder.cv_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //I want bundle cardview here

            }
        });
    }
```

How can I bundle an object in that cardview in recycleradapter A to recyclerview B? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Where is recyclerview B? In the same fragment? If yes are you using same adapter for both? What is meant by bundle cardview?

Comment: recyclerview B in another fragment. I want when I choose a cardview in recyclerview A, it shows in recyclerview B.